# Get list of connected nodes ordered by shortest distance

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array that represents distances between nodes on a graph.  I want to, for a single node, get a list of connected nodes ordered by shortest distance, how can I do that?

```
# create some data
distances = np.array([[0., 1., 2., 3.], [1.,0.,5.,7.], [2.,5.,0.,4.], [3.,7.,4.,0.]]) 
# get just the node I care about, 1
closest_to_node = distances[:,1]
print (closest_to_node)
# outputs [ 1.  0.  5.  7.]
```

I would like to order `closest_to_node` by distance, but my only way of knowing what node it relates to is the order in the array.

I would like a list that was `[1,0,2,3]` or even better since item 1 (value 0) is meaningless in this case `[1,2,3]`

Comment: So, each node is represented as a column, right?

Comment: Shouldn't 1 be ignored in the example?  Why is 0 ignored?  The distance of 0 should be ignored but the index of this is 1 ...

Comment: I was saying item 1, with a value of 0 should be ignored.  Exactly as you say.

Comment: So the answer should be `[0, 2, 3]`

Comment: no [1,2,3] is right.  item 1 in the array (value 0) is the distance from 1 to 1, and since that will always be 0 it could be ignored.

Comment: @nycynik Again, how are defining items? Are you defining items as columns in the array `distances`?

Comment: @Psidom This question deals with distances on a graph, which most probably would be euclidean distances and as such isn't what the linked dup talks about. So, I am re-opening.

Comment: Doesn't `np.argsort(distances[:,1])` suffice?

Comment: @P-robot `distances[:,1]` is chosen as the node from where we are getting distances across all nodes (all columns of distances as far as I understood the data format). `np.argsort(distances[:,1])` won't mean anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you could do -

```
((distances - closest_to_node[:,None])**2).sum(0).argsort()
```

Alernatively, with [`Scipy's cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

idx = cdist(distances, closest_to_node[None]).argsort(0).ravel()
```

Output for given sample -

```
In [147]: ((distances - closest_to_node[:,None])**2).sum(0).argsort()
Out[147]: array([1, 0, 2, 3])

In [148]: cdist(distances, closest_to_node[None]).argsort(0).ravel()
Out[148]: array([1, 0, 2, 3])
```